# Where to find the canons of the Carthaginian Council of 397?

Tags: resource-request, church-council

I need the 33d and the 124th canons (rules) of this Synod. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? https://archive.org/details/acts-of-the-council-of-carthage-397-and-council-of-hippo-393-v-1-2022/page/22/mode/2up

Comment: Not quite, but thanks